# How to integrate Node.js into a PHP Website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

Basically, I want to run my website with PHP using MySQL, and saving the data stored in an input / textarea on the database. This is pretty simple and I have no issues at doing so, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to integrate Node.js into this same website to take the user information previously entered and rendering it realtime. (Probably using Socket.io).

I believe this is a way to explain myself in a much simpler way:

Basic Website (HTML,CSS, JS) -> Processed and saved to Database with PHP -> Node.js takes this data and renders it to make realtime communication possible.

Comment: If PHP stores the data in MySQL then you can easily read them with NodeJS. It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Socket connections (realtime chat/notifications) aren't impossible in PHP, just significantly more difficult. The PHP library Ratchet is specifically built for websockets in PHP.

Comment: simply run two servers on two different ports. and by the way, i think that nodejs is easier, but thats opinionbased....

Comment: I was trying to do something very similar a while back. And I found some excellent  code examples in this repository on GitHub: https://github.com/jdutheil/nodePHP

Comment: Basically, create the node services separate from the PHP, and use interfaces to access whatever PHP you need, and visa-versa.

In the end I ended up remaking my entire site to use node rather then PHP, as it just made it easier to manage and maintain, ha ha.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still unclear. So you wish to:

PHP Website -> SQL -> Node Socket -> Client Socket

If so, what's stopping you from running two different services? There aren't any major technical constraints.